# Getting error SignatureDoesNotMatch .NET in softlayer object storage

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

When I load a image to a bucket in object storage softlayer by https, I got an error:

> The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you
>   provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method

Can any body help?

```
var accessKeyId = <accessKeyId>
var secretAccessKey = <secretAccessKey>
AmazonS3Config S3Config = new AmazonS3Config
     {
          ServiceURL = <https:serviceUrl>,
          MaxErrorRetry = 0
      };
BasicAWSCredentials credentials = new 
          BasicAWSCredentials(accessKeyId, secretAccessKey);
AmazonS3Client client = new AmazonS3Client(credentials, S3Config);
var bucketName = "my-bucket";
PutObjectRequest putRequest = new PutObjectRequest
      {
          BucketName = bucketName,
          Key ="item1", //key,
          ContentBody = "test",
          ContentType ="application/text"
       };
PutObjectResponse response = client.PutObject(putRequest);
```

Comment: It will be useful if you can provide the 'request' or 'code' you are using, you dont need to provide ids

Comment: Hi Albert,
I added code, thanks

Answer (score 0):

The code you are using is working, I was able to send **"item1"** to my bucket. At first time I got the error "Permission Denied", it was because the **bucketName** or **ServiceURL** were wrong, for example, bucketName doesn't exists in ServiceURL.

I think the problem could be the **accessKeyId** and **secretAccessKey**you are using, just in case I recommend you review [IBM Cloud Object Storage - S3 API Intro](https://developer.ibm.com/recipes/tutorials/cloud-object-storage-s3-api-intro/), the page shows how to get the **accessKeyId** and **secretAccessKey** of the object storage you ordered.

Other problem could be the header you are sending, according to [API reference](https://ibm-public-cos.github.io/crs-docs/api-reference)  the value **"x-amz-content-sha256"** is required for uploading objects. The idea is add following line code:

```
putRequest.Headers["x-amz-content-sha256"] = "9f86d081884c7d659a2feaa0c55ad015a3bf4f1b2b0b822cd15d6c15b0f00a08"
```

The value **9f86d081884c7d659a2feaa0c55ad015a3bf4f1b2b0b822cd15d6c15b0f00a08** can be generated using tools like [sha256-hash-calculator](http://www.xorbin.com/tools/sha256-hash-calculator)

I hope this help you.

References:

https://ibm-public-cos.github.io/crs-docs/api-reference

https://ibm-public-cos.github.io/crs-docs/about-compatibility-api

https://developer.ibm.com/recipes/tutorials/cloud-object-storage-s3-api-intro/

https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RetrievingObjectUsingNetSDK.html

Comment: Thank you, Albert. It is a great helpful. It looks like the key issue. I will check. For sha256 header, should the hash be calculated by a developer or the API does it for us? Anyway thank you for your help.

Comment: For sha256 I used the tool http://www.xorbin.com/tools/sha256-hash-calculator, the text I entered was the same that in ContentBody

Comment: I did this, I got the same error. It probably is the access key issue. The thing is when we access the U.S. based storage the code is working, but the same code doesn't work when access Canada based storage. Do you have any idea?

Comment: According to documentation there aren't endpoints in Canada for objects storages S3, see https://knowledgelayer.softlayer.com/faqs/1489. I think, you are trying to access a SWIFT type, if so, you need to use SoftLayer API. See https://sldn.softlayer.com/blog/waelriac/managing-softlayer-object-storage-through-rest-apis

Comment: https://github.com/softlayer/softlayer-object-storage-python and https://github.com/softlayer/softlayer-object-storage-ruby are some APIs to manage object storages

Comment: Thanks, Albert. How can we confirm that the object storage (https://tor.ibmselect.objstor.com) doesn't support s3?

Comment: Patrick, the URL for softLayer object-storages S3 starts with s3-api or only s3, for example s3-api.sjc-us-geo.objectstorage.softlayer.net, see "Current IBM COS (S3) Endpoints" in https://knowledgelayer.softlayer.com/faqs/1489. Other ones are for SWIFT type.

Comment: Also you can identify it by going to "ControlPortal > Storage > Object Storage", that page list all S3 and SWIFT storage types. Click over any S3 and go to "Access & Permissions". If you selects a SWIFT type you need to select the Cluster location, after that click over "View Credentials" to see the URL.